# Problems with compilation in TEX

Tags: compiling, texlive-2019

I have got a mistake with compilation. The name of program is `TEXworks`. 
This is written in a "box": `Could not start Default Compiler`:

```
PdfLaTeX:pdflatex.exe -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode "project name".tex."
```

This is written below

```
Process started: pdflatex.exe -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode "безназвания-1".tex

fmtutil: fmtutil is using the following fmtutil.cnf files (in precedence order): fmtutil: c:/Тexlive/2019/texmf-dist/web2c/fmtutil.cnf fmtutil: fmtutil is using the following fmtutil.cnf file for writing changes: fmtutil: c:/users/1/.texlive2019/texmf-config/web2c/fmtutil.cnf fmtutil [INFO]: writing formats under c:/users/1/.texlive2019/texmf-var/web2c fmtutil [INFO]: --- remaking pdflatex with pdftex

fmtutil [WARNING]: inifile pdflatex.ini for pdflatex/pdftex not found.

fmtutil [INFO]: Disabled formats: 6 fmtutil [INFO]: Not selected formats: 51 fmtutil [INFO]: Failed to build: 1 (pdftex/pdflatex) fmtutil [INFO]: Total formats: 58 fmtutil [INFO]: exiting with status 1

C:\Тexlive\2019\bin\win32\runscript.tlu:907: command failed with exit code 1: perl.exe c:\Тexlive\2019\texmf-dist\scripts\texlive\fmtutil.pl --user --byfmt pdflatex

Running the command C:\Тexlive\2019\bin\win32\fmtutil-user.exe

kpathsea: Running mktexfmt pdflatex.fmt The command name is C:\Тexlive\2019\bin\win32\mktexfmt

Process exited with error(s)
```

This is my text

```
\documentclass [a4paper,14pt] {article}



\author{DEN}


\begin{document}

\maketitle

\end{document}
```

How can l fix it? Thanks for help

P.S. I have added more information, I hope it is enough

Comment: Welcome. I think you didn't share enough info... Pasting here a part of your code that is minimal but reproduces the problem (a MWE) could help.

Comment: Can you provide a `MWE` of your code? This helps to get better suggestions...

Comment: [write18 in texlive](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/76105/what-does-restricted-write18-enabled-mean-and-why-does-texlive-keep-reporting) does this help? Maybe duplicate?

Answer (score 2):

Something went wrong with the installation. Under `.../texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/latexconfig/` resides a file called pdflatex.ini. It seems this is missing in your installation.

Can you call `tlcockpit`and under "Tools" click on "Rebuild all formats"? Or if you use `tlshell`, there also you can rebuild the formats.

Please watch the log, if you get an error while rebuilding the formats. If so, edit your question and provide the error messages.