# How to run minted on Windows

Tags: minted

I am using TeXstudio on windows to compile latex code that requires loading the `minted` package. When the code is compiled following error is thrown:

```
Package minted Error: You must invoke LaTeX with the -shell-escape flag. \RequirePackage{minted}[2011/09/17]
```

This error is thrown although minted package is installed. What mistake am I making?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I enable shell-escape?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/598818/how-can-i-enable-shell-escape)

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/521683/197451